# Schrödinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to prove that map $f\mapsto u$ from initial value to solution of Schrödinger equation is continuous map of $S(R^n)$ to $C^\infty(R^n,R)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $S(R^n)$?  What kinds of topology do you propose on these spaces?

Comment: S is Schwartz space.

Comment: I suspected a much.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling with problems from Rauch book. :'(

Answer (score 2):

$$ \hat u(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \exp(it|x-y|^2) \hat f(y) \, dy \\= \exp(i|x|^2) \int_{\mathbb R^n} \exp(-2it x\cdot y) \exp(it|y|^2) \hat u(y) \, dy \\= \exp(i|x|^2) \hat h(2tx) ,$$
where $h(x) = \exp(it|x|^2) \hat u(x)$.  Now use the fact that the Fourier transform, and multiplying by $\exp(it|x|^2)$, both map $\mathcal S$ into $\mathcal S$.